# getting content of page with 'br' encoding and decoding it by php curl

Tags: php, curl, compression, brotli

I want to get content of [this page](https://www.cryptocompare.com/wallets) by php curl:

my curl sample:

```
function curll($url,$headers=null){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);


    if ($headers){

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $res['headerout'] = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    $res['rescode'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($response === false) {
        $res['content'] = $response;
        $res['error'] = array(curl_errno($ch),curl_error($ch));
        return $res;
    }

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $res['headerin'] = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $res['content'] = substr($response, $header_size);

    return $res;

}
```

response:

```
array (size=4)
  'headerout' => string 'GET /wallets HTTP/1.1
Host: www.cryptocompare.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

' (length=327)
  'rescode' => string '200' (length=3)
  'content' => boolean false
  'error' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 23
      1 => string 'Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings.' (length=88)
```

response encoding is `br` and response content is `false`

I am aware that using `gzip` or `deflate` as encoding would get me a content.  However, the content that I have in mind is only shown by `br` encoding.

I read on [this page](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/tag/brotli/) that `Curl V7.57.0` supports the `Brotli Compression` Capability. I currently have version `7.59.0` installed, but Curl encounters an error as it recieves content in `br encoding`.

now I want to know how can I get content of a page with `br` encoding and uncompress it by php curl ?

Comment: If the response is false, what do you get in `$res['error']`?

Comment: @NigelRen sorry but I updated the question

Comment: The page you mention talks about Curl itself, not the Curl implementation in PHP. Further, in your code, you set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); which acording to the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php means: "a header containing all supported encoding types is sent" - which it says are: "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". Note that "br" is not mentioned here, so no support for Brotli de-/compression. But perhaps this is outdated by now? A way to find out would be: Check which curl version your PHP installation uses: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-version.php

Comment: There's a Brotli extension available for PHP from: https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-brotli - perhaps this could help you solve your problem?

Comment: Myself, I were able to make the upstream server send me content without brotli encoding by setting the user agent string to the value of one that has no Brotli support. Check https://caniuse.com/#feat=brotli to fin out which ones doesn't (hint: I set it to Chrome 49 - existing UAs for it are listed at: https://myip.ms/view/comp_browsers/4301/Google_Chrome_49.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue because one server was only able to return brotli and my PHP Curl-bundled version didn't support Brotli. I had to use a PHP extension: https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-brotli

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output_brized = curl_exec($ch);

$output_ok = brotli_uncompress($output_brized);
```

I checked and, with PHP 7.4.9 on Windows with bundled Curl version 7.70.0, setting the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` option to `''` (like you did) forced the bundled Curl to do the request with one additionnal header `accept-encoding: deflate, gzip` which are the content encodings the bundled Curl can decode. If I omited this option, there was just 2 headers: `Host: www.google.com`  and `accept: */*`.

Indeed, searching the PHP source code (https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=CURLOPT_ENCODING) for this `CURLOPT_ENCODING` option lead to nothing that may set a default value or change value from PHP. PHP sends the option value to Curl without altering it so what I am observing is the default behavior of my bundled Curl version.

I then discovered Curl supports Brotli from version 7.57.0 (https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/bf1571eb6ff24a8299da7da84408da31f0094f66/docs/libcurl/symbols-in-versions) from november 2018 (https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/fd1ce3d4b085e7982975f29904faebf398f66ecd/docs/HISTORY.md) but requires to be compiled with a `--with-brotli` flag (https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/9325ab2cf98ceca3cf3985313587c94dc1325c81/configure.ac) which was probably not used for my PHP version.

Unfortunately, there is no `curl_getopt()` function to get the default value of an option. But, `phpinfo()` gives a valuable info as I got a `BROTLI => No` line which confirms my version was not compiled with Brotli support. **You may want to check your phpinfo to find out if your Curl-bundled version should support Brotli. If it doesn't, use my solution. If it does, more investigation need to be done to find out if it's a bug or a misuse.**

If you want to know what your Curl sent, you have to use a proxy like Charles/Fiddler or use Curl verbose mode.

Additionnaly, for the sake of completness, in the HTTP1/1 specs (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-102), it's said:

```
   If an Accept-Encoding field is present in a request, and if the
   server cannot send a response which is acceptable according to the
   Accept-Encoding header, then the server SHOULD send an error response
   with the 406 (Not Acceptable) status code.

   If no Accept-Encoding field is present in a request, the server MAY
   assume that the client will accept any content coding.
```

So, if your PHP version behaved the same as mine, the website should have received a `Accept-Encoding` not containing `br` so should NOT have replied with a `br` content and, instead, should have replied with a gzip or deflate content or, if it was not able to do so, replied with a `406 Not Acceptable` instead of a 200.

Answer (score -1):

if you using cloudflare, then you can try to disable brotli extension from cloudflare.